# Reducing template policy clutter

Tags: c++, templates

If I have the following template parameters:

```
template <typename T_Key, typename T_Value, typename T_HashFunc, 
    typename T_ExtractKey, typename T_EqualKey, typename T_RehashClass, typename T_HashcodeClass>
  class Hashtable { /* ... */ };
```

Where `T_RehashClass` and `T_HashcodeClass` are two template classes that take in `T_Key, T_Value, T_HashFunc, T_ExtractKey and T_EqualKey` as well. I would like those classes to grab the types from `Hashtable`'s typedef list (all template parameter types in `Hashtable` are typedefined).

Note that `T_RehashClass` and `T_HashcodeClass` can be created by the user as well (defaults are provided) and can have other template parameters if the user wishes.

As it stands, any class that is a `T_RehashClass` must have `T_Key, T_Value` etc. template parameters filled out, which I see as code duplication. I would like the class to somehow have knowledge of `Hashtable` so that it can access its typedefs and deduce `T_Key, T_Value` etc. types automatically by creating its own typedefs. Unfortunately, in this case, I get a cyclic dependency.

How is this type of problem solved generally?

Also note that I am following EASTL where EASTL uses multiple inheritance to inherit from `T_RehashClass` and `T_HashnodeClass` instead and consequently, `Hashtable` has even more template parameters. I wondered if there was a way around it (i.e. not inheriting from both *policies* and have them as template parameters as inheriting from the policies reduces flexibility).

---

One solution that I thought of was to have a template struct that has all the template parameters from `T_Key` to `T_EqualKey`. The `Hashtable` declaration will then be:

```
template <typename T_HashtableParams, typename T_RehashClass = default_rehash_class<T_HashtableParams>, typename T_HashcodeClass = default_hashnode_class<T_HashtableParams> >
  class Hashtable { /* ... */ };
```

The `T_RehashClass` and `T_HashcodeClass` can then take the defaults which will eliminate code duplication. Problem with this approach is that it is more cumbersome for the user to use.

Comment: I'm curious why you need so much flexibility, allowing the user to specify even how the the table gets rehashed...this really seems like YAGNI should kick in - what problem are you trying to solve that requires so much customization?

Comment: `T_ExtractKey` and `T_EqualKey` are redundant (you can extract the key as part of equality test, no need for a separate functor for that), and `T_HashFunc` and `T_HashcodeClass` seem to be, too.

Comment: @CatPlusPlus: Well, in this implementation, there is the option to have the nodes store the hashkey or not. `T_HashcodeClass` has two different implementations, one that assumes a hashkey is stored and the other that does not. As for the others, I am not fully certain either, but EASTL has it. Now I know that is not grounds for including it, but I figured the author knows more than I do and I will eventually understand (the 'eventually understand` part did happen with me on other containers while following EASTL)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See e.g. Modern C++ Design (sec. 1.5.1: Implementing Policies with template-template parameters). The idea is to let T_RehashClass and T_HashcodeClass be template-template parameters. These classes take the T_Key, T_Value and whatever else as their own parameters. To avoid retyping, you can then inherit the needed instantiation of those templates.

```
template <
    typename T_Key, 
    typename T_Value, 
    typename T_HashFunc,      
    typename T_ExtractKey, 
    typename T_EqualKey, 
    template<typename, typename /*, more params */> class T_RehashClass, 
    template<typename, typename /*, more params */> class T_HashcodeClass
>   class Hashtable 
:
    public T_RehashClass<T_Key, T_Value /*, more params */>,
    public T_HashcodeClass<T_Key, T_Value /*, more params */>
{ /* ... */ };
```

NOTE: you really need "class" and not "typename" in front of T_RehashClass and T_HashcodeClass because they are template names, not template types!

Comment: Thanks. That is actually very close to what EASTL is doing. I am reading Modern C++ Design and will revisit the section you pointed out (+1)

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure it's terribly interesting to specify different T_Key and T_Value types for your hash and rehash classes.  If I were going about this problem, I would try and set up a policy for the key/val first.  My inclination is to say that there maybe should be a ValuePolicy instead of grouping it with KeyPolicy, but that is neither here nor there.

```
namespace hash {
namespace detail {

    template<
            typename Key
            , typename Value
            , typename KeyGetter
            , typename KeyComparator>
        class KeyPolicy {
        public:
            typedef Key key_t;
            typedef Value value_t;
            typedef KeyGetter get_t;
            typedef KeyComparator compare_t;
        };

}} // hash detail
```

The `HashTable` isn't valid unless it has the same KeyPolicy as the rehast, etc so don't give it one.

```
namespace hash {
namespace detail {

    template<typename RehashPolicy>
        class HashTableImpl {
        public:
            typedef RehashPolicy rehash_p;
            typedef typename rehash_p::key_policy_t::key_t key_t;
            // typedef ...
        };

    // this doesn't have a specific name, its anything.
    template<typename KeyPolicy>
        class SomeRehashPolicy {
        public:
            typedef KeyPolicy key_policy_t;
        };

}} // hash detail
```

You can add whatever typedefs you want there, obviously.  If I were a stickler in a code review I'd probably ask for things like `rehash_p` and `key_policy_t` to be private.  They are implementation details, really.  The actual invariant you are trying to protect are what are in `key_t`, etc.

Maybe I'm outside the reasonable bounds of etiquette, but my honest opinion is that all this configuration is only interesting to the guy that wrote it.  Not you, not anyone using it.  So I would only expose the HashTable configuration or two that people are actually going to use.

```
namespace hash {

    struct stub {}; // sorry, I'm lazy

    template<typename Key, typename Value>
        class HashTable {
        private:
            typedef typename detail::KeyPolicy<Key, Value, stub, stub> key_p;
            typedef typename detail::SomeRehashPolicy<key_p> rehash_p;
            typedef typename detail::HashTableImpl<rehash_p> impl_t;
        public:
            typedef typename impl_t::key_t key_t;
        };

} // hash

int main(int argc, char ** argv) {
    hash::HashTable<int, double> hash_table;
    return 0;
}
```

Lots of details aren't filled in obviously, but you get the idea.

Comment: I agree that the configuration is interesting only to the person who wrote it. Since I am writing my own Hashtable, it is of interest to me as well :) But I agree, it increases clutter for the end user and may confuse them (probably me down the road). Reference to any future SOer, in the above implementation, the 'detail' classes will take extra space unless base class optimization is used. +1 for a detailed explanation.

Comment: @Samaursa The end user doesn't have to deal with any of the things in detail, unless they want to though.  You can hide that in an entirely different header that an end user doesn't have to know about.  The base class is 'optimizing' anything, its adding extra virtual calls.  If it makes more sense to you then, that has is simpler to maintain.  I would say that is valuable.

Comment: In this case, the `Hashtable` is something the user will not be using directly. They will be using an associative container such as the `hash_map` which will use the `Hashtable` for its logic. So essentially, all this flexibility is there for the library writers (me for now). So yes, I am going to be 'hiding' the details mostly and exposing a 'hash_map' class like you pointed out. As for the base class optimization, I didn't read carefully enough. You are declaring `typedef`s where I thought there was a variable there.

Comment: @Samaursa You would add a variable based on the typedef.  Your HashTable would just be a wrapper for HashTableImpl, adding interface sugar.  It frees users or implementors of HashTable from knowing about HashTableImpl, which is why I prefer it to implementation inheritance.